# MGTwitterEngine - Status updates

Tags: cocoa-touch, twitter

I find that randomly I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the iPhone when updating the status. This occurs pretty randomly.

Anyone have any idea to how this make be fixed?

```
#import "TwitterViewController.h"

NSString *_testUID = nil;
NSString *sImageName;

@implementation TwitterViewController

//Turns NSLogs into comments
//#define NSLog //

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.title = @"Twitter";

    arrayEmotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Happy"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Sad"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Tongue"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Drunk"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Bored"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Love"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Sleepy"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Sick"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Awake"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Shocked"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Angry"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Laughing"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Dancing"];
    [arrayEmotes addObject:@"Confused"];

    [activityView startAnimating];
    [currentActivity setText:@"Logging In"];

    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username_preference"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password_preference"];

    // Make sure you entered your login details before running this code... ;)
    if ([username isEqualToString:@""] || [password isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //Show the UIAlert if no username or password is stored in the settings
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Incorrect username/password stored in the settings." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];        
        NSLog(@"You forgot to specify your username/password in settings.bundle!");
    }

    // Create a TwitterEngine and set our login details.
    twitterEngine = [[[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self] retain];
    [twitterEngine setUsername:username password:password];

    // Get updates from people the authenticated user follows.
    //[twitterEngine getFollowedTimelineFor:username since:nil startingAtPage:0];
    _testUID = [twitterEngine testService];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [arrayEmotes count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [arrayEmotes objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [arrayEmotes objectAtIndex:row], row);
    [btnUpdateMood setEnabled:YES];
}

- (IBAction)updateMood:(id)sender
{   

    NSLog(@"Tried to send status.");

    NSInteger selectedindex = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    switch(selectedindex){
        case 0:
            //Happy
            sImageName = @"Happy";
            break;
        case 1:
            //Sad
            sImageName = @"Sad";
            break;
        case 2:
            //Tongue
            sImageName = @"Tounge";
            break;
        case 3:
            //Drunk
            sImageName = @"Drunk";
            break;
        case 4:
            //Bored
            sImageName = @"Bored";
            break;
        case 5:
            //Love
            sImageName = @"Love";
            break;
        case 6:
            //Sleepy
            sImageName = @"Sleepy";
            break;
        case 7:
            //Sick
            sImageName = @"Sick";
            break;
        case 8:
            //Awake
            sImageName = @"Awake";
            break;
        case 9:
            //Shocked
            sImageName = @"Shocked";
            break;
        case 10:
            //Angry
            sImageName = @"Angry";          
            break;
        case 11:
            //Laughing
            sImageName = @"Laughing";           
            break;
        case 12:
            //Dancing
            sImageName = @"Dancing";
            break;
        case 13:
            //Confused
            sImageName = @"Confused";
            break;
        default: break;
    }   

    [twitterEngine sendUpdate:[@"has changed his/her iMood to " stringByAppendingString:sImageName]];

}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)dealloc {
    //Releasing seems to sometimes cause complete errors.
    //[twitterEngine release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark MGTwitterEngineDelegate methods


- (void)requestSucceeded:(NSString *)requestIdentifier
{
    [activityView stopAnimating];

    //Some animations
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"redToWhite" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];

    //Change background colour of the activity area over 1 second
    [activityArea setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [currentActivity setText:@"Logged In"];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    //End of animations

    NSLog(@"Request succeeded (%@)", requestIdentifier);

    if ([requestIdentifier isEqualToString:_testUID])
    {
        NSLog(@"[TWITTER UP]");
    }

}


- (void)requestFailed:(NSString *)requestIdentifier withError:(NSError *)error
{

    currentActivity.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]];
    NSLog(@"Twitter request failed! (%@) Error: %@ (%@)", 
          requestIdentifier, 
          [error localizedDescription], 
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSErrorFailingURLStringKey]);

}


- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)identifier
{
    NSLog(@"Got statuses:\r%@", statuses);
}


- (void)directMessagesReceived:(NSArray *)messages forRequest:(NSString *)identifier
{

    NSLog(@"Got direct messages:\r%@", messages);
}


- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)identifier
{
    NSLog(@"Got user info:\r%@", userInfo);
}


- (void)miscInfoReceived:(NSArray *)miscInfo forRequest:(NSString *)identifier
{
    NSLog(@"Got misc info:\r%@", miscInfo);
}


- (void)imageReceived:(UIImage *)image forRequest:(NSString *)identifier
{
    NSLog(@"Got an image: %@", image);
}




@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few leaks (twitterEngine (you are retaining it when alloc/init does the job fine) and arrayEmotes (never gets released) to name the two I spotted right away), and you could have another issue related to sImageName when you send the update (notice how it isn't defined on a scope other than inside the switch statement - I don't really know if this would definitely cause issues, it's just something I always try to avoid. I can see it potentially causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Anyway, try using GDB to step through your program to figure out what object exactly is being released early. A lot of headaches can be solved simply with GDB.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, it's always a retain/release problem. Your code also has at least one leak (look where you're creating the twitterengine).

I suggest you read [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Tasks/MemoryManagementRules.html). They'll help you find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue too, and it's weird; even though I am cleaning up my MGTwitterEngine object properly, one of its callbacks is still getting called after I release the object.  This is causing some sort of access violation when the callback is somehow called from the dead.